# SQL Server : concatenating numbers into varchar field works but into char field does not work. any ideas?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

When I run this SQL code:

```
declare @a as int=0;
declare @b as int=1;
declare @c as char(4)='c'
declare @d as varchar(4)='d'  

set @c = @c + cast(@a as char(1)) + cast(@b as char(1))
select @c

set @d = @d + cast(@a as char(1)) + cast(@b as char(1))
select @d
```

it returns

```
c
d01
```

Is there a way to successfully convert numbers to char and add to a `char(n)` variable?

I also wonder why it is happening.

Comment: How long is the string in `@c` before you append to it? Hint: 1 is not the answer. - From another view: What is the difference between `char(n)` and `varchar(n)`?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms176089.aspx)

> char [ ( n ) ]
>
> Fixed-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the
> string length and must be a value from 1 through 8,000. The storage
> size is n bytes.

`@a` Variable is already occupied with 4 bytes, so you cannot add any more characters to it.

```
declare @c as char(4)='c'
```

Here already `@c` is occupied with **four bytes** even though you have passed only `c` which is one byte.

When you assign `@c` with `@c + cast(@a as char(1)) + cast(@b as char(1))`
which translates to 4+1+1 = 6 which `@c` cannot hold.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @a as int=0;
declare @b as int=1;
declare @c as char(4)='c' -- here @c = 'c   '
declare @d as varchar(4)='d'  

set @c = RTrim( @c ) + cast(@a as char(1)) + cast(@b as char(1))
select @c

set @d = @d + cast(@a as char(1)) + cast(@b as char(1))
select @d
```

If you don't trim @c, is already full (with 3 blanks) so all the rest actions like `+ cast(@a as char(1)) + cast(@b as char(1))` are truncated.